# send variable from basic js to angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, variables, send

I want to send variable in basic JS to angular in function. I want to send variable `value1`. as you are seeing the code I declare `value1` and after script is closed I want to send the value of `value1` to the function `doImportAll` that declared in other file.

```
<script>
      var value1='hi';
      var openFile = function(event) {
          var input = event.target;

          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(){
              var text = reader.result;
              var node = document.getElementById('output');


              var lines = reader.result.split('\n');
              for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
                  console.log(lines[line]);
              }
              value1=lines[0];
              node.innerText = lines[2]
              document.getElementById('clicking').click();
          };
          reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
      };
  </script>
  <button id="clicking"  class="btn btn-md" ng-click="doImportAll(value1)" my-i18n="modal_importAll"></button>
  <div>
      <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange="openFile(event)">
  </div>
  <div id='output'>
      ...
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi,I am not sure why you would like to do that? why not work with angular and do it within the controller and have the logic processed in some factory for the file reader?

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, there's no reason **not** to do this within an angular service. But if for whatever your reason you wish to have this function not run inside angular, you can assign value to the global window object like so:

```
window.value1 = lines[0];
```

It will then be accessible to the angular via the window object. This is not the most elegant solution and you should really consider restructuring your FileReader logic to work within angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the value into your angular app and then use that

```
angular.module('App').value('yourVar', value);

angular.module('App').controller('Controller', function ($scope, yourVar) {
    console.log(yourVar);
});
```

Here is working example
http://plnkr.co/edit/rUCXJ0GmEb5iWf8OiBs6?p=preview